# vue table component which supports drag&drop of columns and configurable column visibility

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I am looking for an vue table as a npm package which supports drag & drop of columns and configurable column visibility.

In React projects I usually worked with Mui Datatables which provides a good option for visible columns.

While researching I discovered npm vue-tables-2 which seems to be a good alternative for Vue.js projects. However I am missing a feature to drag & drop columns. Can you recommend any package which supports this feature out of the box?

Comment: Configurable column visibility is possible with vuetable. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/wq540wrrnw. And in combination with [Vue.Draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) you can change the order of the columns in the config overlay.

Comment: @RWAM, thank you it worked great

Comment: @RWAM feel free provide your comment as an answer as it answers my question